# Prolog predicate where two items are associated but not equivalent

Tags: prolog

I haven't programmed in Prolog for years and am struggling with a simple block of test code (I'm trying to solve a logic puzzle for fun...):

```
aboard(jack, blackbird).
aboard(jim, blackbird).
aboard(donna, blackbird).
aboard(david, north_star).
aboard(sandy, north_star).

shipmates(A, B) :- A \= B, aboard(A, X), aboard(B, X).

shipmates1(A, A) :- !, fail.
shipmates1(A, B) :- aboard(A, X), aboard(B, X).
```

The `shipmates` and `shipmates1` rules are two different attempts to accomplish the following: I want to pair all passengers who are on the same ship but are not equivalent to each other.

For example, I want `shipmates(jack, jack).` to be `false`.

When I query this with fully-qualified arguments, I get the expected answers:

```
3 ?- shipmates(jack, david).
false.

4 ?- shipmates(jack, jack).
false.

5 ?- shipmates(jack, jim).
true.
```

However, when I want all of Donna's shipmates, it doesn't seem to work:

```
6 ?- shipmates(donna, X).
false.
```

I was expecting:

```
X = jack ;
X = jim ;
```

*NOTE: I get the same wrong results with `shipmates1`.*

So please take pity on a very amateur Prolog programmer (who is not doing homework for a class!) What very obvious thing am I doing wrong?

**Version:** SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.0.2)

Comment: Replace `A \= B` by `dif(A,B)`

Comment: Why is it better to use `dif(A,B)` in this case?

Comment: With `dif/2`, the order of goals does not matter. Also, monotonicity is not violated, whereas `A \= B` does violate monotonicity as you have seen. With `A \= B` you are responsible to guarantee **sufficient instantiation**. With `dif(A, B)` it always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
shipmates(A, B) :-
    aboard(A, X),
    aboard(B, X),
    A \= B.
```

By calling the `aboard/2` predicate before the `A \= B` goal, you ensure that both `A` and `B` will be instantiated, thus making the comparison meaningful.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I did not fully understand the need to qualify, or instantiate the variables before using them in a comparison.